# XPath / XQuery: find text in a node, but ignoring content of specific descendant elements

Tags: xpath, xquery

I am trying to find a way to search for a string within nodes, but excluding ythe content of some subelements of those nodes. Plain and simple, I want to search for a string in paragraphs of a text, excluding the footnotes which are children elements of the paragraphs.

For example,

My document being:

```
<document>
   <p n="1">My text starts here/</p>
   <p n="2">Then it goes on there<footnote>It's not a very long text!</footnote></p>
</document>
```

When I'm searching for "text", I would like the `Xpath / XQuery` to retrieve the first p element, but not the second one (where "text" is contained only in the footnote subelement).

I have tried the `contains()` function, but it retrieves both p elements.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and easy XPath 1.0 expression that selects the wanted text-nodes even in much more complex XML documents. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I want to search for a string in
>   paragraphs of a text, excluding the
>   footnotes which are children elements
>   of the paragraphs

An XPath 1.0 - only solution:

**Use**:

```
//p//text()[not(ancestor::footnote) and contains(.,'text')]
```

**Against the following XML document** (obtained from yours but added `p` s within a `footnote` to make this more interesting):

```
<document>
    <p n="1">My text starts here/</p>
    <p n="2">Then it goes on there
        <footnote>It's not a very long text!
           <p>text</p>
        </footnote>
    </p>
</document>
```

**this XPath expression selects exactly the wanted text node**:

```
My text starts here/
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//p[(.//text() except .//footnote//text())[contains(., 'text')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`/document/p[text()[contains(., 'text')]]` should do.

Comment: Thanks Martin! The only problem with this one, is that is selects 'text' in p, ignoring the content of *all* subelements. I only want to ignore the footnote elements.

Comment: Can you update your question with some more representative XML sample so that it becomes clearer what the requirements are? Does `/document/p[descendant-or-self::*[not(self::footnote)]/text()[contains(., 'text')]]` suffice?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, as a complement to the other answers, I've found this workaround that also seems to do the job:

```
//p[contains(child::text()|not(descendant::footnote), "text")]
```

Comment: This isn't a valid XPath expression. The union operator (`|`) requires both of its operands to be nodes, but the return type of the `not()` function is xs:boolean -- any compliant XPath engine *must* raise an error.

Comment: Ouch, you're right Dimitre, Oxygen raised an error. Weird, the expression worked in my PHP script!