# Getting only immediate text out html with webdriver and selenium 2.22

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver

So I have to parse HTML that is structured as such

```
<div>
    Hello
    <div name="DONOTWANT">
        Text that I dont want and other junk
    </div>
    World
</div>
```

I require a solution that would retrieve the immediate text in a block of HTML. In this example, I would want "Hello World" while ignoring all other text. Are there any suggestions as to how I can do this with webdriver and selenium? I am programming in java but, if you have a solution in another language that can be translated over, I would take that as well.

Currently if I have something like

```
String foo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div")).getText();
```

foo would contain "Hello Text that I dont want and other junk World" which is less than optimal.

Comment: Maybe this Question ca help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735453/xpath-xquery-find-text-in-a-node-but-ignoring-content-of-specific-descendant

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem before and I had to solve it using java script with the help of the JavascriptExecutor.

You can check this question I had asked before on this site - [Reading text using selenium webdriver(xpath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811066/reading-text-using-selenium-webdriverxpath)

Let me know if this solves your problem.